# How to alight ListView to TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

Hi Im having problem aligning data i show in a ListView to the Textview that Im using as a header.Im a newbie and i wanted originally use a LayoutTable but its complicated if you can give me an idea on that score will be great.

I want everything to be parallel to its header

See Xml below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/linearlayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/w_r"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:text="what"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="where"
        android:id="@+id/f_l"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:text="???"
        android:id="@+id/w_f"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:text="Storing"
        android:id="@+id/S_r"
        android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="look"
        android:id="@+id/looks"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp" />
</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listarecdatos"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearlayout2"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
```

Comment: Do u hvave any screen shot ?

Comment: They wont let me show the pictures because i dont have 10 point yet. but there is a link. thank you in advance

Comment: "`[enter code here]`"... Are you really that lazy?

Comment: Personally, I'd recommend a GridLayout or TableLayout

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use weights for both layout containers, each columns must have weight of 1 in your header layout and in your item layout

EDIT - Add sample code

Your Activity/Fragment that will contain the header, and the view holder of each item layout should look like this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

If you want to distribute in a horizontal then you should set `layout_height="0dp"` instead of `layout_width`

Comment: Please give a code example to support less advanced users.